# Group and simplify about 10 k sublayers?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, creative-cloud

I have a map (exported from some GIS-program) to a PDF with several thousands sublayers. The problem is that the simplified map layers on top of the layers hierarchy are probably just a smaller proportion of the total number of layers. 
So I am trying to simplify the document in order to delete the various layers that are not visible. 
The problem is that the document is really slow (Using a fairly proper basic HP Z workstation with a Quadro card) so I'd like to get some clues how to fast select and delete perhaps 100-500 sublayers at once?

Comment: Highlight layers/objects in the Layers Panel and drag them to the trash can on the Panel.

Comment: Is it OK if it takes like 40 minutes or more for the computer to select them?

Comment: You don't need to actually *select* anything. Just highlight the layers. It should be instantaneous, or practically instant. Highlighting layers in the Layer Panel doesn't actually select the objects on that layer. However, if you remove the layer... all objects on that layer will be removed.

Comment: Do these layers have anything in common? If they're all the same colour, or have the same stroke or something you can bulk select them that way.

Comment: Well that's reassuring to hear, however I get the program "hanging itselft" while working in the background". The document has 476076 paths and it say also 76308 open, 339768 closed). I guess it's the closed ones that a "under" the visible layers that I would like to delete since I don't need them.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. I manage to delete some of the layer groups, but in the end got a new file that is only hade the relevant data.

Answer (score 1):

As Scott pointed out, there's a difference between selecting **layers** and selecting **objects**. Selecting layers takes up almost no resources, whereas selecting objects does.

In the example below, I've only selected the layer, **not** the object inside it:

[image: layer selection in Illustrator]

And in the following example I've selected the objects in the layer (notice the blue square and the highlight on the artboard):

[image: Object selection in Illustrator]

The key to deleting layers without you computer grinding to a halt is thus: select only layers (batch select them with ctrl or shift), then delete them by dragging them to the bin:

[image: Deleting layers in Illustrator]